# How to add "input type=file" buttons dynamically in a multiple file upload formula [PHP, MySQL & JS]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem by adding "**"input type=file"**" dynamically.

I have a formula where the user can select multiple files and can type a title under each selected file, before the user click on the **Upload** button.
When the forumla gets loaded, i want that there is only 1 select button and 1 title field. If the user selected 1 file, then there should show up a new "select file" button and a new title field. (Add buttons dynamically)

I think my problem has something to do with **file.setAttribute("name", "sel_file");** in the JS part and with this for loop
**for($mf = 0; $mf < count($_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name']); $mf++)**

in the php part.
It seems php cannot work with "sel_file"

Anyway, here is my code (**The whole code is in 1 php file**):
(and ignore the security issues, I will do this later)

**PHP Part**

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");

// If upload button is clicked ...
if (isset($_POST['upload']))
{ // Get post title
  $post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['post_title']);

  $sql_p = "INSERT INTO posts (post_title) VALUES ('$post_title')";
  if (mysqli_query($db, $sql_p))
  {
    $post_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
    for($mf = 0; $mf < count($_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name']); $mf++)
    {
      $file = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'][$mf];
      $tmp_file = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'][$mf];
      $target = "files/". basename($file);
      $file_title = (isset($_POST['file_title'][$mf])?$_POST['file_title'][$mf]:"");
      if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $target))
      {
        echo "File: ".$file." &#10004;<br>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "File: ".$file." - Upload failed<br>";
      }
      $sql_f = "INSERT INTO files (file, file_title, post_id) VALUES ('$file', '$file_title', $post_id)";
      mysqli_query($db, $sql_f);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

**HTML & JS Part**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Project | XY</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function()
      {
        document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function()
        {
          // Create a div
          var div = document.createElement("div");

          // Create a file input
          var file = document.createElement("input");
          file.setAttribute("type", "file");
          file.setAttribute("name", "sel_file"); 
          // Create a text input
          var text = document.createElement("input");
          text.setAttribute("type", "text");
          text.setAttribute("name", "file_title");

          // add the file and text to the div
          div.appendChild(file);
          div.appendChild(text);

          //Append the div to the container div
          document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="frame_form">
      <form method="POST" action="TEST.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="post_title">
          <input type="text" name="post_title" placeholder="* Post Title *">
        </div>
        <br>
        <form>
           <div>
              <input type="button" value="add" id="add" />
                <div id="container">&nbsp;</div>
           </div>
         </form>
        <br>
        <div id="upload_button">
          <button type="submit" name="upload">+upload</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Before i had no JS code, instead i had the following code, and it worked very well, but was not dynamically ...:

```
    <?php $sfq = 2 ?>
    <?php
        for ($sf=0; $sf<$sfq; $sf++){ ?>
        <b><?php echo $sf+1 ?></b><br>
        File: <input type="file" name="sel_file[<?php echo $sf ?>]"><br>
        Title: <input name="file_title[<?php echo $sf ?>]"><br>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: When you set the attribute for the `name` of that file `input` ... you give it a name of just `sel_file`... when you are using them as an array in PHP. Try giving it the name of `sel_file[]`. (same with changing `file_title` to `file_title[]`)

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked ! :) Type it as an answer and i will accept it after the time limit!

Comment: Done. As a side note, I encourage you to create a programmatically *named* file for saving on the server... as relying on the file name from a users posted input can be a bit dicey ;) I refer to `$file = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'][$mf];`. I tend to use timestamps, or a GUID to prevent any dupe clashing and nefariousness.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, i'm a newbie in php, mysqli and js, but i learn a lot every week. I will try to implement your tips in my code!

Comment: Learn by doing! :) Happy coding, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your PHP is expecting those two fields to be arrays, you need to be sure you are setting the `name` of those `input` fields to behave as an array when posted.

So where you have the JS of:

```
      var file = document.createElement("input");
      file.setAttribute("type", "file");
      file.setAttribute("name", "sel_file"); 

      var text = document.createElement("input");
      text.setAttribute("type", "text");
      text.setAttribute("name", "file_title");
```

Change the `name` assignments to:

```
      var file = document.createElement("input");
      file.setAttribute("type", "file");
      file.setAttribute("name", "sel_file[]"); 

      var text = document.createElement("input");
      text.setAttribute("type", "text");
      text.setAttribute("name", "file_title[]");
```

Note the brackets. This makes php turn those multiple named inputs into an array, so the rest of your PHP will work correctly.